# JQuery Validate: Change error class, replacing another class

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

What I want to do is for the error to take the place of another class in my html, and change to another class for the styling.

e.g. in my HTML I have

```
<div id="firstname" class="cfield">
    <span>First Name:</span>
    <label><input id="first" name="first" type="text">*</label>
    <span id="firstDesc" class="desc">Only characters</span>
</div>
```

I want the error message to take the place of the class `desc`, and then change to class `error` so the style can change (to red text). Is this possible?

In my JQuery I have:

```
function checkForm() {
$('#contactform').validate( { 
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'desc',
    rules: { 
        first: {
            required: true,
            minLength: true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        first: {
            required: "You must enter a first name",
            minLength: "Your first name must have more than 2 characters",
        }
    }
} );
}
```

Comment: Could you please guide https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177300/visualforce-jquery-validation-example-does-not-show-calendar-popup-why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code had a few problems.

1. You misspelled the `minlength` rule as `minLength`.
2. You would not set `minlength` to `true`.  It gets set to a parameter representing the number of characters.  `minlength: [2]`
3. The custom message gets a placeholder, `{0}`, which represents, and is automatically replaced by, the parameter you set for the rule.  `minlength: "Your first name must have more than {0} characters"`
4. You also would not put the `.validate()` method inside of a function.  The `.validate()` method is only used for ***initializing*** the plugin on your form, so it only gets called *once* on DOM ready.
5. If you're trying to change your hard-coded `span` into the error message, then you do not need to change the `errorClass`.  You can leave it as `error`.  Simply use the `errorPlacement` function to change the content of your hard-coded `span` into the error message.  Using jQuery DOM traversal techniques, the hard-coded `span` is the next element after the parent element of the input.

   ```
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
       $(element).parent().next('span').html(error);
   }
   ```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/48c593kd/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#contactform').validate({
        errorElement: 'span',
        rules: {
            first: {
                required: true,
                minlength: [2],
            }
        },
        messages: {
            first: {
                required: "You must enter a first name",
                minlength: "Your first name must have more than {0} characters",
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $(element).parent().next('span').html(error);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you are taking about this kind of validation css change

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerForm").validate({
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'desc',
    rules: { 
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength : 2
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "You must enter a name",
            minlength: "Your first name must have more than 2 characters",
        }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
span.desc {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id='registerForm' name='registerForm' method='post' action='' >   
 <label for="field">Name: </label>
 <input type='text' name='name' id='name' />
    <br/>
 <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

</form>
```

Comment: Yes, but the `desc` class is used before as a hint, and I only want it to change if it is an error

Comment: I'm not getting what you want

Comment: It needs to take the place of the `desc` class, and if it is an error come up in red text